# Use multiple version of truffle in linux

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, dapps

Can we use multiple version of truffle in linux just like python ?
If yes then how can we use specific version ?

Answer (score 1):

Truffle being a npm package can be used with different versions.

You can have different projects using different truffle versions. All you need to do is to specify in `package.json` file whichever truffle version you want to use.

After that, you can use `npm install` in that directory to install the required version for that project.

Comment: I did something like that :
"dependencies": {
    "truffle": "^3.2.1",
    "truffle-default-builder": "^2.0.0"
  },

But looks like its not working.